# correct cell alignment

Tags: tables

In the first row contents are not aligned to centere

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
 \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Awqqf & Bfwqf & Cfwq & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{D} \\ 
        \cline{4-5}
        & & & L & U\\
       \hline 
        P & & & &\\
        \hline
        Pa& & & &\\
        \hline
       \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome, if i add the parts that make the code snippet compilable, i see everything centered. Please provide a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: `\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{D}` should be `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{D}` but other than that everything seems centred as specified, what output did you expect?

Comment: I want A, B, C at center of row (vertically center)

Comment: `\multirow{2}{*}{A}`, ... and `multirow` package in preamble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For vertical centering of a cell across `n` rows, load the `multirow` package and use `\multirow{n}{*}{...}` directives.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
        \begin{tabular}{|*{5}{c|}}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Awqqf} & \multirow{2}{*}{Bfwqf} & \multirow{2}{*}{Cfwq} & 
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{D} \\ 
        \cline{4-5}
        & & & L & U\\
       \hline 
        P & & & &\\
        \hline
        Pa& & & &\\
        \hline
       \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```